# Quadratic variation of two processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have the following question:
Let $M$ be a local martingale and let $A$ be a finite variation process.
Can we say anything about quadratic variation of such processes?
Honestly, I thought it is $[A,M]=0$, but I know that I am wrong.

Comment: can we assume that the local martingale is continuous?

Comment: Yes, it can be for example, even a Wiener process.

Comment: If $M$ is a wiener process then, take a partition $0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n=T$ of the interval $[0,T]$.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n |M_{t_i}-M_{t_{i-1}}|\cdot |A_{t_i}-A_{t_{i-1}}|\leq \sup_{|t-s|\leq|\Delta|,t,s\in[0,T]} |M_t-M_s|\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n |A_{t_i}-A_{t_{i-1}}|$$

by uniform continuity of $M$ this tends to $0$ as the mesh of the partition goes to $0$.

Comment: If you are working with a (proper) local martingale I guess you can use a localizing sequence, use the same reasoning and the let the stopping time go to infinity, although I am not sure how to do it properly. I guess you could use a partition of the interval $[0,T\wedge\sigma_n]$ but I am not absolutely sure.